# How to remove a characters in string php

Tags: php, string, replace, preg-replace

I am stuck with this. I tried json_decode but it gives me an error.

How can I remove the `"[]"` and the `' " " '` characters of my string?

I have a string with this values `["Red Cat","Black Cat","Red Shoes"]` i want to remove and make my string like these: `Red Cat, Black Cat, Red Shoes`

Here i tried to make like this:

```
$data = json_decode($display_data);
```

and also i tried something that I've searched: `$data = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', ' ', $display_data);`

Comment: If the _value_ of your string variable is actually `["Red Cat","Black Cat","Red Shoes"]`, then there is no reason why `json_decode` should throw any errors.

Comment: @04FS can you help me how to remove the strings that i want using preg_replace?

Comment: No, I would simply use `json_decode` for this. If that is not working for you, then your input data must be something different, than what you said it was. So, please provide a _proper_ [mre] of your issue first of all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments: 'use json_decode'. [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e178e07d07733334ff51645c49a5bf94a00783c9):

```php
$display_data = '["Red Cat","Black Cat","Red Shoes"]';
$data = json_decode($display_data); // Here we have array of strings
$result = implode(', ', $data); // Convert array back to one string

echo $result; // here we have "Red Cat, Black Cat, Red Shoes"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove whitespace using this

```
<?php 
$display_data = ["Red Cat","Black Cat","Red Shoes"];
$array = array_filter(array_map('trim', $display_data));
$data = implode(', ', $array);
echo $data;
```